# perl open files with variable in filename

Tags: arrays, perl, file

I try to open a list of files in a folder. Eventually I want to insert a HTML-Snippet in it. So far I can open the folder and read the list in an array. That´s fine. But when I try to open the files by using a variable as filename, I get an error message every time ("permission denied"). No matter if I use $_ or other variations of putting the values of list items in variables. I have found similar questions here, but didnt find the solution so far. Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($line);

opendir (FOLDER,"path/to/folder/./") or die "$!";
my @folderlist = readdir(FOLDER);
my @sorted_folderlist = sort @folderlist;
close(FOLDER);

foreach (@sorted_folderlist) {
  my $filename = $_;
  open (READ, ">", "path/to/folder/$filename") or die "$!";
  # do something
  close (READ);
}
```

What is the mistake here? And how would I open files with using a variable as filename?

Pjoern

Here is my changed code in order to answer 1:

```
my $dh; 
opendir $dh, "dir/./" or die ... 
my @folderlist = grep { -f "dir/$_" } readdir $dh; 
close $dh; 
my @sorted_folderlist = sort @folderlist; 

foreach my $filename (@sorted_folderlist) { 
  open my $fh, "<", "dir/$filename" or die ... 
  open my $writeto, ">", "new/$filename" or die ... 
  print $writeto "$fh"; 
  close $fh; 
  close $writeto; 
}
```

Comment: I've edited both of your code examples to add indentation. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Proper indentation is an important tool to help people understand your code. If you're asking a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, then surely it is only polite to make that as simple as possible for them.

Comment: Hmm. It's very kind that you edited your question and now show your working code after you applied @tinita's proposal. I do understand that you want to share that and tell us "look how I made it working". But now it's no longer a question. It already includes an answer. People will try to figure out what's wrong with your 2nd code snippet and find … nothing. /// I'm not sure how to handle this. Anybody an idea? @Dave?

Comment: Uh, I edited my question because I actually thought it would be polite to show that I appreciated the answer. I can delete the second code example, if its reasonable.
@DaveCross: Sure, I´ll look at it.

Comment: @PerlDuck: I think the question is still as clear as it was. And there are still obvious problems in the second code example - for example `print $writeto "$fh"` is very strange :-)

Comment: @Pjoern You added `print $writeto "$fh";`.  That prints to `$writeto` alright, but what it prints is the filehandle `$fh` itself (evaluating it under `""` is not needed and doesn't change anything.); so it print something like `GLOB(0x1820a68)`. Instead, read from that input, process the line, and print that to output `while(my $line = <$fh>) { process-$line; print $writeto $line; }`

Comment: @zdim Your´re right, I´m getting GLOB... as return. Cant get the solution. I´ll look at your answer and try to figure it out.

Comment: @zdim Works now! Thanks. Your hint helped finally ...

Comment: @Pjoern Great. So .. a [filehandle](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Files-and-I/O) is your "handle" to a resource, in this case a file. To read from a file you normally use [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators), as `while (my $line = <$fh>) { ... }` to read one line at a time or `@lines = <$fh>;` to get all of them. To print to a file you say `print $fh 'what-to-print';` When you do `print 'output';` it goes to the default filehandle, `STDOUT` (so to the terminal). See the explanation in [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).

Comment: @Pjoern Finally, you actually send a list to `print` (what may be just one item), like `print 'this', 'that', 'more';` or `print @lines;` (same for `print $fh LIST;`). And normally you'd eventually add a newline, `"\n"` (here you need double quotes).  Or, if you say `use feature 'say';` on top of your program then you can do `say @lines;` and a newline gets appended.

Comment: @zdim Thanks for explanation. I theoretically know about scalars and arrays. But i got confused by using a variable as filename for open file for reading. Now the problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several issues in your code.

The first, causing the error, probably, is that `readdir()` will return `.` and `..` also, but these are directories. So you try to write to `directory/.`.

Second, your error message contains `$!`, which is good, but you don't output the filename. Then you would have seen your mistake.

Third, you call a filehandle you open for writing `READ`.

Also, you should use lexical filehandles nowadays.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my $dh, "dir" or die $!;
# read all files, not directories
my @folderlist = grep { -f "dir/$_" } readdir $dh;
close $dh;
my @sorted_folderlist = sort @folderlist;

foreach my $filename (@sorted_folderlist) {
    open my $fh, ">", "dir/$filename" or die "Could not write to dir/$filename: $!";
    print $fh "foo...\n";
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: @tinita: Thanks for your answer, with your example I think I can get my code working - although I didn´t understand every detail. My usage of readdir() is the crucial error I think. Thanks for your tips to modern code, too :). I´ve posted my code so far in my question (@Dave Cross). Im working on it.

Answer (score 6):

You've got errors and good practices cleared up in [tinita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47840414/4653379).

I'd like to comment on a possible improvement, of building the file list with full paths to start with.

- Use [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) on the output of `readdir` to add directory to each file, then filter that

  ```
  my @files = grep { -f } map { "$dir/$_" } readdir $dh;
  ```

  or, implementing [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)'s (filtering) functionality in the  `map` block

  ```
  my @files = map { my $fp = "$dir/$_"; -f $fp ? $fp : () } readdir $dh;
  ```

  Here if `$fp` isn't [`-f`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) we return an empty list which gets flattened in output, thus vanishing.
- Use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), which directly gives you the full path <sup>†</sup>

  ```
  use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';
  my @files = grep { -f } glob "$dir/*";
  ```

  where [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html)'s `bsd_glob()` overrides `glob` and handles spaces in names nicely.

Note a difference: the `*` in `glob` does not pick entries that start with dot (`.`). If you want those as well, change it to `glob "$dir/{*,.*}"`. See linked `File::Glob` docs.

---

**Update**   to correct the edit (addition made) to the question, also discussed in comments

Once the full-path filenames have been read into `@files`

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $out_file = 'new_' . $file;
    open my $writeto '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";
    open my $fh,     '<', $file    or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    while (my $line = <$fn>) {
        # process $line and build what need be written to the new file
        my $new_line = ...   
        print $writeto $new_line;
    }
    close $writeto;
    close $fh;
}
```

(Or, if the filenames aren't full path build the full path in the `open` call.)

Filehandles get closed when opened again so you need an explicit `close` only for the last files.  Then you can declare `my ($fh, $writeto);` variables before the loop, use `open $fh ...` (no `my`), and close the filehandles after it. But then you have those variables outside of `foreach` scope.

Documentation:

- [Files and I/O in perlintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Files-and-I/O)
- [perlopentut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) and 
  [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) (and [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html))
- [`<>` operator in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)

---

<sup>†</sup>   The `glob "$dir/*"` carries the possibility for injection bug, for very particular directory names.
While this can come about only wiht rather unusual names it is safer to use [escape sequence](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters)

```
my @files = grep { -f } glob "\Q$dir\E/*"
```

Since this escapes spaces as well the `File::Glob` with its `bsd_glob()` isn't needed.

Comment: `glob` is the preferred method for scanning a directory; `File::Find` is preferred for scanning sub-directories too.